# Yahoo Finance API for previous day information

Tags: javascript, rest, yahoo-finance

I'm wondering if anyone knows how to get stock information from the previous day using the Yahoo Finance API? I am using JavaScript and axios to make the API call from a react app and everything is working fine:

```
axios.get('https://rest.yahoofinanceapi.com/v11/finance/quoteSummary/'+this.stockName+'?modules=assetProfile%2CsummaryProfile%2CsummaryDetail...(the rest of them)', {
            headers: {
                'x-api-key': MyKey
            }})
```

But on the JSON returned I cannot find anything for the previous day other than `prevDayClose`. Specifically, I need the previous day low and high. I have searched some other posts on this forum but nothing that I could find solves this specific issue. I don't think posting the JSON returned here would help, but can do so if someone thinks the answer would be there. Also I'd prefer to keep the format the same and not have to download anything, but if that's the only way I am open. I was hoping there was a parameter to add a date, then I could just send it the day before today, but I don't see anything like that. Any advice would be appreciated.